# How do I fix a missing script error and npm start?

Tags: reactjs

```
{
  "name": "trelloclone-client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/hlee686/TrelloClone-client.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/hlee686/TrelloClone-client/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/hlee686/TrelloClone-client#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "dependencies": "0.0.1",
    "node_module": "0.0.0",
    "start": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "description": ""
}
```

When I npm start, I get an error as below.

Jakes-MacBook-Air:TrelloClone-client jslee$ npm start

> trelloclone-client@1.0.0 start /Users/jslee/Desktop/TrelloClone-client
>   index.js

sh: index.js: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! trelloclone-client@1.0.0 start: `index.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the trelloclone-client@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jslee/.npm/_logs/2020-04-09T10_18_00_148Z-debug.log

How can I fix it and run npm start?

Thank you

The above is my package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure where to start, but do you have Node and Npm correctly installed and on your path?  Try the below using terminal in the same folder as the package.json file.

```
node --version

npm --version
```

If the above return a version number, as least you know that node and npm are fine.

Have you installed the dependencies?

Finally, what's in the index.js file?  Have you tried a simple 'hello world' type index.js just to make sure things hang together?

Comment: node and npm are fine and I installed dependencies by "npm install dependencies". Yet, it gives me the same error over and over again.

Comment: For the install, you should only need to type 'npm install'.  Beyond that, I'd be thinking the index.js isn't right.

Comment: I did npm install and when I npm start, I get an error as follows: missing script: start. Any idea?

Comment: npm start should work as start is a valid arg for npm.  You could try and force it to run start by doing 'npm run-script start', though I'd imagine you'll get the same issue.